# I'm trying to select all rows with numbers that have more than one row associated with it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of 13000+ products. I have a column called product number that has a number representing each product and all of it's variants.

Not every product has more than one variant.

I want a new sheet with one row for every product that has more than one variant.

For example: If there are 14 options under product 1, I want there to be one row of product 1. If product 2 has only one entry, I don't want it on the list at all.

Is this something that can be done in excel, or am I going to have to transfer this data to a database and do this with SQL?

[image: image of sample data]

Comment: Is the number of variants part of the part number itself? I'm not sure I can picture this set

Comment: The sheet has about 20 columns. sku, product name etc. One of the columns is product number. The list was sorted by product category, and as we went through each item, it was given a number. So there could be 20 1's on the sheet, followed by a single 2, a single 3, and then 30 4's

Comment: So if a product number shows up in more than one row it's assumed that it has more than one variant?

Comment: Use two dictionaries. If a value doesn't exists in the first one, load it there. If it does exist in the first one, check if it exists in the second. If it doesn't exist yet in the second, load it. Get the `.Keys` of this second list when done.

Comment: yes, that's how we did it

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: I added an image to the post of some sample data. seems you can't paste formatted excel data here

Comment: @JdvV thanks, I'll start on that

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, you can look into `Dictionaries`. Let's imagine the following data:

[image]

***Running the following code:***

```
Sub Test()

Dim dict1 As Object: Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim dict2 As Object: Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim arr As Variant
Dim lr As Long, x As Long

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A2:A" & lr)
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If dict1.Exists(arr(x, 1)) = True Then
            If dict2.Exists(arr(x, 1)) = False Then
                dict2.Add arr(x, 1), 1
            End If
        Else
            dict1.Add arr(x, 1), 1
        End If
    Next x
    .Range("C2").Resize(dict2.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict2.Keys)
End With

End Sub
```

***Will result in:***

[image]